# INSERT INTO inserts a row full of nulls

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql, database-cursor

I have the following code (a function which calls another one).Turns out in my second function the 'INSERT INTO' line tries to insert a row full of nulls.Why is this happening?

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION LIMPIA_REPETIDOS() 
    RETURNS VOID AS $$

    DECLARE 
        REP RECORD;
        cursor1 CURSOR FOR SELECT DISTINCT usuario, fecha_hora_ret, tiempo_uso FROM auxi ORDER BY tiempo_uso DESC;            

    begin
        open cursor1;
        LOOP
            FETCH cursor1 INTO REP;
            EXIT WHEN NOT FOUND;
            PERFORM GUARDA(REP.usuario, REP.fecha_hora_ret);
        END LOOP;
        CLOSE cursor1;
    end;

    $$ LANGUAGE PLPGSQL;



    CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION GUARDA
    (myid auxi.usuario%TYPE, my_time auxi.fecha_hora_ret%type) RETURNS VOID AS $$
    DECLARE
        mycursor CURSOR FOR
        SELECT * FROM auxi
        WHERE myid = usuario AND my_time = fecha_hora_ret
        ORDER BY tiempo_uso;
        CANT INT;
        mystruct RECORD;

    BEGIN
     OPEN mycursor;
     CANT = 0;

            LOOP
                     FETCH mycursor INTO mystruct;
                     EXIT WHEN NOT FOUND;
                     IF CANT = 2 THEN 
                             INSERT INTO RECORRIDO_FINAL VALUES(mystruct.periodo, mystruct.usuario, mystruct.fecha_hora_ret, mystruct.est_origen, mystruct.est_origen, crear_fecha_hora_devolucion(mystruct.tiempo_uso, mystruct.fecha_hora_ret));
                     END IF;
                     CANT := CANT + 1;
            END LOOP;
            IF CANT = 1 THEN
                     INSERT INTO RECORRIDO_FINAL VALUES(mystruct.periodo, mystruct.usuario, mystruct.fecha_hora_ret,  mystruct.est_origen, mystruct.est_destino, crear_fecha_hora_devolucion(mystruct.tiempo_uso, mystruct.fecha_hora_ret) );
            END IF;
            CLOSE mycursor;

            END;


    $$ LANGUAGE PLPGSQL;
```

What I'm trying to do here is to select rows from a table called 'auxi' and then transfer them to another one. The thing is when I have two or more rows in 'auxi' with the same values for 'usuario' and 'fecha_hora_ret' I have to sort those by 'tiempo_uso' and then select the second one.

Answer (score 1):

When EXIT WHEN NOT FOUND gets executed the variable `mystruct` will not contain any value since you have already gone through all the rows in the cursor.

So when you exit the loop for the case that the cursor contained 1 row only the INSERT will get executed with a `mystruct`that is empty.